# returning template types from non-template parameterized methods

Tags: c++, templates

To define a templated class, I consider three different files. The declaration is in a `.h` file, the methods implentations are in a `.cpp` file, and explicit instantiations are included in a `.inc` file (by adding a line at the end of the .cpp, e.g: `#include "bar-impl.inc"`).

Now, here's my problem. I've two template classes, say: `Foo<S>` and `Bar<T>`.
Inside of the `Bar<T>` class, I've a method that returns a template Type `FooType*` (  which with my explicit instantiation I would like it to be, for example, `Foo<float>*`)

```
template<class T>
class Bar{
 ....
 template <class FooType>
 FooType* doSomething(int);
 ....
};
```

Since the compiler does not know what `FooType*` is, I tried to explicitly instantiated the `doSomething` method in the `bar-impl.inc` file.

```
//bar-impl.inc
template class Foo<float> * Bar<float>::doSomething(int);
```

However, it didn't work and I get an error of: `no matching function for call to
‘Bar<float>::doSomething(int&)’
make: *** [main] Error 1`

Does anybody knows if it's possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods templates work exactly the same way as function templates. You need to explicitly instantiate them upon use unless the template parameters can be derived from the call.

So you don't really need to make a specialization, what you need to do is specify the `FooType` upon use:

`Bar<float> somevar; somevar.doSomething< Foo<float> >(somevalue);`

If you always want to return `Foo<T>*` then just use `Foo<T>* doSomething(int);`

Comment: Thanks! but since I separated the declaration from the instantiation of the template class, I need in any case to do the explicit instantiation, don't I?

Comment: @Javier If you put your template code inside `.cpp` files, then you need to explicitly instantiate all templates, because the compiler can't do that for you. But the problem you are having is unrelated. You have a templated method and trying to call a non-template method (which doesn't exist).

Comment: ok, so, I should have: template<class T>
class Bar{
 ....
 template <class T>
 Foo<T>* doSomething(int);
 ....
}; is that what you're suggesting? And what if I wouldn't like always to return Foo<T>*. Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Do you mind in including a `main.cpp` example on how could I call the doSomething method?

Comment: `undefined reference to Foo<float>* Bar<float>::doSomething<Foo<float> >(int)` after calling the method in main as `Foo<float>*pFoo=NULL; pFoo=pBar->doSomething<Foo<float> >(num);`

Comment: thanks! I just needed to add sth. in the `bar-impl.inc` and it is the following instantiation `template Foo<float>* Bar<float>::doSomething< Foo<float> >(int);`