# Compilation error in explicitly instantiated template methods

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I've two different template classes. One of them has a member function that returns a pointer to an object of the other template class. 
Currently, I'm not able to compile the code below and any suggestions are really welcome.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <foo.h>
#include <bar.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ...
    int nParam;
    ...

    CFoo<float> * pFoo = NULL;
    pFoo = new CFoo<float>();

    CBar<float> * pBar = NULL;
    pBar = pFoo->doSomething(nParam); // error: no matching function for call to ‘CFoo<float>::doSomething(int)’

    ...

    delete pFoo;
    delete pBar;

    return (0);
}
```

#### foo.h

```
#include <bar.h>

template < class FOO_TYPE >
class CFoo{

    public:

        ...

        template < class BAR_TYPE >
        CBar<BAR_TYPE> * doSomething(int);
        ...
};
```

#### foo.cpp

```
template < class FOO_TYPE >
template < class BAR_TYPE >
CBar<BAR_TYPE> * CFoo<FOO_TYPE>::doSomething(int nParam){
    ...
}
#include "foo-impl.inc"
```

#### foo-impl.inc

```
template class CFoo<float>;
template class CFoo<double>;

template CBar<float>* CFoo<float>::doSomething( int );
template CBar<double>* CFoo<float>::doSomething( int );
template CBar<double>* CFoo<double>::doSomething( int );
template CBar<float>* CFoo<double>::doSomething( int );

/*
I also tried the explicit instantiation in the last line, but I get the error below:
template-id ‘doSomething<CBar<float>*>’ for ‘CBar<float>* CFoo<float>::doSomething(int)’ does not match any template declaration
*/
// template CBar<float>* CFoo<float>::doSomething < CBar<float> * > ( int );
```

Consider that I need to call the `doSomething` method inside of a `member function` of a third class.

#### myclass.cpp

```
template < class FOO_TYPE, class BAR_TYPE >
void CMyClass<FOO_TYPE, class BAR_TYPE>::doSomeWork(CFoo<FOO_TYPE> * pFoo){
    ...
    int nParam;
    ...
    CBar<BAR_TYPE> * pBar = NULL;
    pBar = pFoo->doSomething<BAR_TYPE>(nParam); //error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

    delete pBar;
    ...
}
```

Note that, I had [a similar problem that I posted a while ago in this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217216/returning-template-types-from-non-template-parameterized-methods), but by trying to adapt the suggestion to my code, I couldn't solve the bug. I hope, my post is valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler can't deduce the template arguments -- it doesn't know whether you want to call `CFoo<float>::doSomething<float>(int)`, `CFoo<float>::doSomething<unsigned int>(int)`, or whatever.  So, you have to explicitly tell it what the template arguments are:

```
// Explicitly call the function with BAR_TYPE=float
pBar = pFoo->doSomething<float>(1);
```

Comment: thanks it solved the bug! I thought that since `pFoo` is of type `float`, it should be enough for the compiler to know which function to call. On the other side, when does an explicit instantiation as:`template CBar<float>* CFoo<float>::doSomething < CBar<float> * > ( int );` is valid?

Comment: @Javier: Nope - the compiler can deduce template arguments from the parameters passed in (e.g. if you had `template <class C> void doSomething(C)`, then if you passed in an integer parameter, it would deduce that `C = int`), but not from what happens with the return value.  You can always do an explicit instantiation, but it may not always be a good idea; I'm not sure what that snippet you posted is intended to mean, since it's not syntactically valid.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! About my snippet, if you're referring to the `1`, since I was not able to find the bug, I was trying to debug it manually. So actually, it's a variable passed as argument. Furthermore, do you've an idea when the following instantiation is valid: `template CBar<float>* CFoo<float>::doSomething < CBar<float> * > ( int );`?

Comment: @Javier: The syntax `template CBar<float*>` is invalid.  If you're trying to define the template specialization of `doSomething` with `BAR_TYPE=float`, then write `template<> CBar<float>* CFoo<float>::doSomething>( int ) { ... }`.  Note the extra `<>` after the `template`.

Comment: great! Now, I'm trying to call `doSomething` inside the member function of a third class: `pBar = pFoo->doSomething<BAR_TYPE>(nParam);`. I'm getting a compilation error, by doing this. I inserted a new paragraph into my original post, where I'm illustrating the error. Why is this call not valid? I basically replaced the `<float>` of the function call in the `main.cpp` with `<BAR_TYPE>`.